# Column type inference for heterogeneous vector of ints and floats [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I am computing some article metrics for many different wikipedia pages, like article length and references per section. The type of these metrics is either int or float. I have stored them in a dict of dicts, and am not trying to get them into pandas to create some histograms and statistics. When I try to populate the DataFrame, even if I call `float()` on all my metric values, the type of the df column is still object not some numerical type. When it is not a numerical type, I cannot call numerical operations on the list. How do I get pandas to recognize this column as numerical?

```python
arts = {"Q774": 
{"metrics": 
    {"fr": {"informativeness": 1.3500775193798449, "referencerate": 0.0026265931794695143, "completeness": 202.4, "numheadings": 19, "articlelength": 23224.0}, 
    "en": {"informativeness": 7.602386920360031, "referencerate": 0.003673816096835846, "completeness": 308.8, "numheadings": 36, "articlelength": 47090.0}, 
    "sw": {"informativeness": 0.0650467289719626, "referencerate": 0.0, "completeness": 18.400000000000002, "numheadings": 1, "articlelength": 232.0}} } }

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['qid','lang','metric','val'])
for qid, attribdict in arts.iteritems():
        for attrib, langdict in attribdict.iteritems():
            if attrib == 'metrics':
                for lang, metrics in langdict.iteritems(): 
                    for metric_name, metric_val in metrics.iteritems():
                        df = df.append({'qid': qid, 'lang':lang, 'metric':metric_name,'val':float(metric_val)}, ignore_index=True)

In [258]: df['val']
Out [258]:
0        1.350078
1     0.002626593
2           202.4
3              19
4           23224
5        7.602387
6     0.003673816
7           308.8
8              36
9           47090
10     0.06504673
11              0
12           18.4
13              1
14            232
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Comment: I see also there is `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` which does not seem to cast my column to floats as intended, although, Ipython notebook seems to print it more prettily afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can cast to float with `convert_objects`:

```
>>> df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
>>> df[:2]
     qid lang           metric           val
0   Q774   fr  informativeness      1.350078
1   Q774   fr    referencerate      0.002627
>>> df.dtypes
qid        object
lang       object
metric     object
val       float64
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried this on my data, but the val column remained as object. However when I launched a fresh kernel and tried my own example it worked. I wonder what was happening in my kernel before? Oh well. Thanks again.

Comment: @notconfusing you could probably forgot to reassign datframe, as convertation is not happening in-place, but creates a new dataframe.